# What is exact meaning for Update Anomaly in DBMS?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In the below picture we can update the RSize to 500 by using where clause.
ex : update table_name set Roomsize=500 where Room=H940. so it will update the all columns data where Room H940 size to 500. what exactly issuse with update in this scenario.

[image]

Comment: "we have to update all other columns where room=...". It is unclear statement

Comment: have to update only one column data i.e Room H940 value size has increase to 500

Comment: Probaby should be: *we have to update the room size in  all other rows where room= 'H940'"*

Comment: yes correct. so i can write a query like update table_name set Roomsize=500 where Room=H940. so what will the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the `UPDATE` but in the table definition.

The apparent *primary key* is the `course_no` and each course is assigned a specific `room` (number).

So far so good. But the table contains also *attribute* of the `room` (here `room_size`).  This violates the [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and should not be used in *relational database design*.

The obvious reason is that this setup enables - if you update e.g. only line 3 - that one room gets *two different sizes*. This is of course wrong and you may call it an  *update anomaly*.

The correct solution is to define separate `room` table related to your `course` table.

Comment: Yes, the database is not even at 1NF. I would recommend the OP to normalize the datanase structure to 3NF at least.